# Running code written for Quarkus in non-Quarkus environment

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I am trying to use code originally written for Quarkus. It uses only dependency injection and `@ConfigProperty` annotations in non-Quarkus enviornment.

I would like to provide configuration and run Quarkus context in programmatic way and get some beans out of it.

I am going back and forth through all the guides on Quarkus page but I cannot find any way how to do that.

Coming from Spring I am looking for Quarkus analog of this code:

```java
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AccountConfig.class);
AccountService accountService = context.getBean(AccountService.class);
```

Comment: If the code you are interested in running standalone is not using any Quarkus extensions, you can bootstrap a CDI container with [Weld SE](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-4.0/en-US/html_single/#weld-se). See the examples, the basic usage is as simple as `Weld weld = new Weld(); WeldContainer container = weld.initialize(); AccountService accountService = container.select(AccountService.class).get(); /* use your bean */ container.shutdown();`. Don't forget to add an empty beans.xml under META-INF!

Comment: You can also use the MicroProfile annotations by using the Smallrye libraries manually